# Modify existing "Fill in blank" App Script box to be drop down with selection of Gmail Template Subject Lines (and optionally apply associated filter)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

(Important Context: I am using a managed Google workspace that has steadfastly refused to authorize any Chrome extensions, instead insisting we "Stay within the Google Workspace tools." Each day, I am provided an updated spreadsheet with a list of contacts that are (currently) grouped roughly into 12 categories, each of which is supposed to receive a different personalized email from my work Gmail account).

Here is a link to a simplified copy of my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MgZC1gaPUHmEo1scZmP74uMFqamhCtu9HqUK6mc1Xm0/edit?usp=sharing

I have recently tested and executed the general Mail Merge (Google Sheets to Gmail) app script provided at this source: https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/14yLibz0C1Z3hikwRTT0u-1-cReszvXqe23NeLpcukFcGohOO51dZr3zm/edit

However, the base code as written requires copy/pasting the exact Gmail Template subject line into the dialog box that pops up. Additionally, I think it requires that I pre-filter the sheet for the set of recipients I want to send to.

**Primary Objective**: How I can modify the code to provide a drop down (or multiple choice) box with a list of my Saved-to-Gmail templates?

I'm assuming it would involve some modifications to this portion of the code:

```
function sendEmails(subjectLine, sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {
  // option to skip browser prompt if you want to use this code in other projects
  if (!subjectLine){
    subjectLine = Browser.inputBox("Mail Merge", 
                                      "Type or copy/paste the subject line of the Gmail " +
                                      "draft message you would like to mail merge with:",
                                      Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
                                      
    if (subjectLine === "cancel" || subjectLine == ""){ 
    // If no subject line, finishes up
    return;
    }
  }
  
  // Gets the draft Gmail message to use as a template
  const emailTemplate = getGmailTemplateFromDrafts_(subjectLine);
```

But I'm not sure how to pull a list of current Gmail templates to populate the list (alternatively, I could use a tab in the spreadsheet with the list of subject names, if pulling the templates from Gmail just isn't possible).

**Secondary Objective**: It would be great if I could also set this script to automatically filter the spreadsheet by the template subject name.

Theoretically, I could add a column to my spreadsheet such as: "Subject"
Through other calculations (quite a few if-thens, managed by others), I can have each row assigned one of several Gmail Template subject names. The goal would be for the app script complete these primary steps in this order before moving on to the "sending emails" stage:

1. Collect the desired template name from the dialog drop down/MC
2. Apply filter to Column X titled "Subject" matching the results from #1
3. Proceed with the rest of the app script in sending emails.

**What I've tried:**
**Objective 1:** Select Template Names
I have tried several searches on how to extract information from Gmail templates, with no results.

If necessary, I could add that list of template subjects directly into the app script (and update it as needed), if I could be provided with a basic skeleton with a few placeholders such as "template1" "template2" and "template3."

So far as converting the free response prompt into a drop down response, all I've found so far is this generic information on creating a prompt: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs
However, I didn't see anything on how to convert this into something more dropdown/multiple choice.

I found a similar request here: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/234991555/dialogbox-with-prefilled-values-to-choose-from?hl=en
The recommendation was to create a custom dialog, but I haven't yet found how to make that custom dialog a dropdown/multiple choice.

**Objective 2:** Filter spreadsheet by selection
Using the macro recorder, I created this piece of App Script code: (In this example, filtering for "Subject1")

```
function Filter() {
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(19, criteria);
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .setHiddenValues(['', 'Subject2', 'Subject3'])
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(19, criteria);
};
```

This code would filter for Subject 1. However, I'm not sure what the best way forward is from here. A few ideas I have:

1. Name and place a copy of this filter for each of the 12 Gmail templates into the main mail merge script, and add some line of code to the script to call the copy that corresponds with the subject selected from the dialog.
2. Place one copy of this filter within the mailmerge script, modify it to set All values hidden, then modify it to set unhidden the subject selected by the dialog
3. Some other, probably better than I've thought of, method.

I would appreciate any and all suggestions!

Comment: How do you identify the drafts that are templates?

Comment: who wrote the original code?

Comment: Your second link returns and error

Answer (score 0):

This get's the draftt subjects along with their id's:

```
function getTemplates() {
  let templates = GmailApp.getDrafts().map(d => [d.getMessage().getSubject(),d.getId()]);
  templates.unshift(["Subject","id"]);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(templates).replace(/],/g,'],\n'))
}
```